# What is !r called?

Tags: python, syntax

I am seeing this for the first time. I wanted to know what the `!r` in the last line of the code called so that I can search about it. I found this piece of code on: https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/08/10/a-guide-to-python-lambda-functions/

```py
class Puppy:
    def __init__(self, name, cuteness):
        self.name = name
        self.cuteness = cuteness

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Puppy({self.name!r}, {self.cuteness!r})"
```

Comment: [here's the relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a format string [conversion flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) that tells the formatter to call `repr` on the object before formatting the string.

> Three conversion flags are currently supported: `'!s'` which calls [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) on the value, `'!r'` which calls [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) and `'!a'` which calls [`ascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii).